# scrape data which appears while hovering in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrape

I want to scrape data in the website: https://en.macromicro.me/collections/19/mm-oil-price/182/mm-oil-expectation-index

Basically, I know how to use selenium to extract static data such as the text on a typical Newpaper site like BBC, DW.

However, when I want to scrape the data on the macromicro. It is totally different situation:

- the data hidden in the graph/chart
- the data appears only when the mouse hovering and disappears when the mouse moves out

for example, when I hover on the line, the data shows (you can say it pop up).

How can I scrape the data?

[image]